# Python web scrape date time and replace string date in url

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website from 2002 to the date time now. The website url looks like this

https://   thewebsiteurl.php?date=29-08-2019

I want to replace the date numbers, from datetime now until 05-01-2002. Or another way from 05-01-2002 to datetime now. Each scrape session (each day) the url will be replaced with the date in form dd-mm-yyyy.

I searched datetime module and seems like it doesn't do this kind of job. Actually I don't really know because I'm new in programming. Real calendar will avoid of 30th Feb, 4 years a 29th Feb, years that have 366 days, etc.

Long story short I want to replace strings of every single day the date on the url above from 05-01-2002 to the date of today. How to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import datetime
urls = []

sdate = datetime.date(2002, 5, 1) 
edate = datetime.date.today()

delta = edate - sdate      

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    urls.append('https://thewebsiteurl.php?date=' + str(day))

print(urls)
```